# ASP.NET Querystrings

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, query-string

I got this code in order to build an url for the link using a querystring from the current page. The problem is.... It doens't work. Any suggestions?

```
<asp:hyperlink ID="link1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%@("Equipamentos.aspx?ID_Cliente=")+Request.QueryString    ("ID_Cliente").trim.tostring()%>'>Equipamentos</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you say what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: The link appears as a link but it doesn't have any link.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gah, my eyes!  Try doing this in code behind instead:

```
link1.NavigateUrl = "Equipamentos.aspx?ID_Cliente=" & Request.QueryString("ID_Cliente").Trim().ToString()
```

You have to use "&" instead of "+" because this is VB.NET, not C#.

Comment: Thank you very much... At least someone nice with a useful answer

Comment: The "ToString()" at the end is when you are not sure that Trim() returns String?:)

Comment: Actually "+" works for string concatenation, too. "&" is preferred because there's no chance that it will do an implicit cast followed by an arithmetic add.

Answer (score 1):

Your ASP.NET code should look like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="link1" runat="server" NavigateUrl=''>Equipamentos</asp:HyperLink>
```

And then add this in code behind:

```
this.link1.NavigateUrl = string.Format("Equipamentos.aspx?ID_Cliente={0}", Request.QueryString["ID_Cliente"].Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
<asp:hyperlink ID="link1" runat="server" 
  NavigateUrl='<%= ("Equipamentos.aspx?ID_Cliente=") 
  + Request.QueryString("ID_Cliente").Trim().ToString() %>'>
  Equipamentos</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Why downvote without an explanation ? Exactly, I have done this way in many places in my project.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
<%@ %>
```

tags are for directives, such as registering controls. You need a

```
<%= %>
```

tag, which is called a code evaluation block.

Something like

```
<%= (5+5).ToString() %>
```

is what you need - try your code in there.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to set the `NavigateUrl` of the link in this way.  Try something like this:

```
<asp:hyperlink 
    ID="link1" 
    runat="server">Equipamentos</asp:HyperLink>
```

And then in your codebehing or a script tag do this:

```
link1.NavigateUrl = "Equipamentos.aspx?ID_Cliente=" 
    + Request.QueryString("ID_Cliente").Trim().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can't use "<%= %>" with server controls. So you can:

```
1. Leave it as a server control and follow Andrew Hare's (or similar) answer.
2. Use client control: "<a />" and "<%= %>" should work.
```